# Ubuntu boot login prompt?

Tags: boot

Recently restarted my computer after updates. I get pass grub and a login prompt with a black background came up to log in with a user name, password. After the login the prompt
"name@name-GA990FXA-UD3:~$" this came up. I'm not sure where to go from here. I realize that GA990FXA-UD3 is my motherboard.

I attempted older version which gave me error due no detection of devices. Mouse and keyboard didn't work. Recovery mode and repair.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
startx
```

or

```
sudo lightdm
```

Check this: [Bug #824140 "Boot stops after "checking battery state...""](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/824140)

Try solutions posted in comments.

Comment: startx didn't do anything. sudo lightdm went down a checklist of item. It stop at checking battery state

Comment: I attempted the sudo apt etc... and what i do notice that stick out is the Fatal error no screen found.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to switch off acpi before boot. To do this type do the following.

When you get to the grub bootloader select the kernel you want to boot (usually the top one; just select it do not hit enter) and press 'e'.

You should get a screen looking something like this
[image]

Look for the line that starts with

```
linux /boot/etc....
```

and add the following text behind the word 'ro'

```
noacpi
```

now hit 'ctrl+x' to restart with these changes made